# How to connect gsm modem to c# program in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, gsm

I have a project to use sms function in my program.
The idea is to connect GSM modem to a C# program, and i prefer to use my old cellphone as the GSM modem.

The problem is in many driver not supported in Windows 8, and i have no idea on how to connect GSM to a C# program.

Asking for help in connecting my cellphone to C# program and tutorial to perform sms function.